# how can i make a in app purchase without google play?

Tags: android-studio, in-app-purchase, credit-card

I want make a in app purchase without **Google Play** in android studio?

I want make in app purchase that people can purchase something with visa card, credit card,etc..**(WITHOUT GOOGLE PLAY)**

Thank You..

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure you can't. Isn't that like the main stipulation for security reasons?